# What level does lightning start at in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How high does lightning spawn? My current abode sits above the clouds and I'm wondering if it can be struck by lightning. Is there some level lightning appears or does it come from the "top" of the sky?

Comment: Corollary: If you build in a pit (say down near bedrock), can you still get struck by lightning?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It comes down the "top" of the map, I have been struck by lightning at the top of a tall tower before!

I'm not sure whether a bedrock level pit would allow you to survive, going to test this now

**EDIT:**

I was in the bottom of my pit mine today and got <strike>hit</strike> killed by lightning, then immediately thought of this post. -_-

Comment: No update in a day, looks like soulBit didn't survive.

Comment: Heh, i'm OK! I never ended up finding thunder storm to test this :(

Comment: [Induce one!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6KaFRadc_0&feature=player_detailpage)

Answer (score 6):

**127**, and it vertically strikes at the first *solid* block below. This logic is unrelated to how it is rendered.

Comment: If you have proof of this, there's [another question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20715/does-lightning-strike-on-an-angle) that could use your help.

Comment: @Nick I've answered that.